# HTTP Multipart request in Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, afnetworking

### **Prologue**

So I'm making the *iOS* version of an *android* app. all the webservices are already setup but they dont have much detailed documentation, so I choose to go with inferring that from the android code. The project is complete except for one small thing - **A HTTP Multipart request**.

### **What I Need**

I need to implement a *web-request* from `java` into `objective-c`. What this does is upload an *image* along with the *user ID* to the server and obtains a response. Here is the relevant Java code :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest=new HttpPost(Constant.server_url+"usermain/Profileimagesave");
String fileName = String.format("File_%d.png",new Date().getTime());
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, fileName);
            
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("file", bab);
reqEntity.addPart("WebID", new StringBody(SharedPreferenceSession.getValue(getApplicationContext(), "WebId")));
postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

### **What I Tried**

I have been trying for almost a week to mimic this code into `objective-c`. Here's what I could manage after taking in [stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34510979/3894781):

```
[manager POST:urlstr parameters:nil
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
  [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                              name:@"blahblah.jpg"
                          fileName:@"blahblah.jpg"
                          mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

  [formData appendPartWithFormData:[webid dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                              name:@"WebID"];
}
     progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
      }
      failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"%@",[error.userInfo objectForKey:JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey]);
}];
```

I have been trying a lot of variations of the above code, but as I dont have a clear understanding of a multipart request, I feel like I'm going around in circles.

### what I got

I am getting a 500 error from the server.

> ## PHP warning
>
> #### copy(../UserData/ThumbPhotos/MOB274565CCM_20151230062220.): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> 1773         $login1=$login->LoginID;
> 1774         $curr_date=date("YmdHis");
> 1775         $currentname=$webid."_".+$curr_date;
> 1776
> 1777         //echo "file size:".$_FILES['file']['size'];
> 1778         $info = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
> 1779         $ext=$info['extension'];
> 1780         $filename="{$currentname}.{$ext}";
> 1781         $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
> 1782         $targetPath="../UserData/ThumbPhotos/".$filename;
> 1783         $targetPath1="../UserData/UserPhoto/".$filename;
> 1784         move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath);
>
> #### 1785         copy($targetPath,$targetPath1);
>
> 1786         $userfiles=new UserFiles;
> 1787         $userfiles->LoginID=$login1;
> 1788         $userfiles->FileActualName=$filename;
> 1789         $userfiles->FileTempName=$filename;
> 1790         $userfiles->ThumbImage=$filename;
> 1791         $userfiles->Type="IMAGE";
> 1792         $userfiles->ProfileImage=0;
> 1793         $userfiles->deletedStatus=0;
> 1794         $userfiles->UploadBy=$login1;
> 1795         $userfiles->UploadDate=date("Y-m-d");
> 1796         $userfiles->deletedby=NULL;
> 1797         $userfiles->PasswordProtected=0;

### What could help

I am not able to wrap my head around what is going on in the above code as I am not well versed with how HTTP requests function. So anything that can help me understand this is welcome, may it be a **working code example**, tips to **debug the request** or comments on **how these things work**.

**or**

The android code is working fine. So is there any way that I could inspect the outgoing request on both the android and iOS apps and maybe try to match them up by trial and error?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Are you interested to use AFNetworking? That could save some code and time...

Comment: @Stefan yup sure. but I am not sure how to port the java code into obj-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).
In this case, you want to upload some image, so I will give you code for that:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                name:@"files"
                            fileName:photoName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
[formData appendPartWithFormData:[key1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                            name:@"key1"];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: No problem. This code will upload one image on server... You can append more images... If you have some parameters that you need to send, just use dictionary... If you want to know something more, please let me know, so I can edit my answer...

Comment: It seems to be in 3.0, I'm using 2.0... Please read https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide and see code for 3.0... This is new update. I think that you only need to change  `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to `AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];`

Comment: add "text/html" to acceptableContentTypes set in AFURLResponseSerialization class. Just search for "acceptableContentTypes" and add @"text/html" to the set manually.

Comment: thanks for your support. I switched over to AFNetworking (updated question). totally worth the learning curve. so now I am able to properly debug the error. but it still throws an error. any ideas?

Comment: If you're getting 500 server code error, that's on the server side... http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try out this for upload any image using NSMutableURLRequest

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_URL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:_YOUR_IMAGE_DATA]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"posttype\"\r\n\r\n%@", postType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"postimgtext\"\r\n\r\n%@", postTextType] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userid\"\r\n\r\n%@", USER_ID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (!error) {
     NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"response : %@", response);
}
```